# Zend Server configuration issue

Tags: php, zend-framework, wamp, zend-server-installation

I am pretty familiar with Zend, I am already working on Zend, but was simply copying Zend libraries while creating new project, so today I installed Zend server to try all this using command line.

I already had WAMP installed in D:

I followed instructions on http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/learning.quickstart.create-project.html

- I installed Zend in C:,
- created project using cmd in some other place in D:, c
- configured vhost and host files. (I am using windows 7).

All files and folders were created properly.  But **when I tried to access project in browser as per told in "Checkpoint" section in above guide, I saw the previous wamp projects listed instead of "Welcome page"**

I changed the port in vhost file from 80 to 8080 and in host file, added 127.0.0.1:8080 address because while installing Zend, I have given web server port as 8080. Also I have given Zend server interface port as 10082.

Can anybody tell me if I have missed anything or gone wrong anywhere ?????
Thanks.

Comment: I would love to hear reason/s for downvoting also.. :)

Comment: sorry it's obvious but I have to check. Have you restarted WAMP since you made changes to the vhosts file?

Comment: just didnt realize that apache and wamp are related to each other through vhosts.. :)

Comment: No problem, I would delete this question to avoid further down voting. Happy coding :)